# Javascript xmlhttp - Get name of variable in JSON

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

JSON:

```
{
    dynamicname1: {
        0: "x",
        7: "y",
            ....
    },
    dynamicname2: {
        0: "xx",
        7: "yy",
        14: "zz",
            ...
    }
}
```

`dynamicname1` and `dynamicname2` are dynamically generated for each request to the server (PHP).

Can I get the name of `dynamicname` for each time request and value?

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        // data[0].name; // i want to get name of variable
        $.each(data[0], function(){       
            alert(this);
        });
        $.each(data[1], function(){       
            alert(this);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you get for this code...??

Comment: If you're JSON really looks like that, it's invalid. Keys must be in (double) quotes, e.g. `"dynamicname1": {`, `"0": "xx"`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve your dynamic names using the `Object.keys` method ([link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) :

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        var keys = Object.keys(data); // keys = ["dynamicname1", "dynamicname2"]

        // do whatever you want with it...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `for in` loop to iterate over the properties (keys) of an object:

```
for(var key in data) {
    // key will be dynamicname1 in the first iteration, dynamicname2, etc
    console.log(data[key][0]); // x, xx, etc
}
```

Or, since you seem to be using jQuery anyway, you could use [`jQuery.each()`][1] which does much the same thing:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    // key would be dynamicname1, dynamicname2, etc
    // value would be the object that corresponds to that key, so equivalent to data[dynamicname1], etc
});
```